# How can we differentiate receiving a phone call when app is in use and closes app after clicking on Home button?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When user clicks home button or received a call application every time goes to

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

then

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application.
```

I have checked with putting logs in all delegate methods of AppDelegate.

Is there any restriction by Apple that we can't differentiate these two states ?

Comment: Why would you want to treat them differently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895815/detecting-the-type-of-iphone-interrupt

Comment: Richard, as per my app requirement i need to display an alert when user has picked up a call and back to the app.I need to display a different alert when app was closed by home button.