# Dismissing iphone low battery alert programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, alert, volume

I'm writing a camera app where the user will be unable to access the touch screen without significant effort. I'm using the (+) volume button to take videos, I would like to either:

1) Ignore the 10% and 20% volume alert that pops up entirely. I'd be surprised if I apple let me do this.

OR

2) Allow the user to dismiss the popup with the (+) button. i.e. dismiss the popup programmatically.

There are SO questions related to this, I've tried disabling battery monitoring from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834506/detect-low-battery-warning-ios/14834620) when the batter hits ~11% and 21%, but that does not work. This other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895815/detecting-the-type-of-iphone-interrupt) talks about detecting all interrupts, and going through all the views when a battery interrupt happens, its a good idea but since its from 2009 and is a bit hacky (might be rejected by the store) I thought I'd ask you all whether you knew of any other way I might do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. The low battery alert is a system alert. It can't be controlled from any 3rd party app.

Comment: Darn, I sort of expected that. Does that mean that the method in my second link doesn't work anymore? When the alert pops up my app isn't even in an active state anymore right? Its not just a view on top of my view that my view controller can manipulate?

Comment: The 2nd link you reference is all conjecture. There is no claim any of it would ever work. It was all just theory. In fact, one the comments to the answer states it didn't work.

Comment: After press to dismiss the alert, it will enter applicationDidBecomeActive.